# Unable to POST data from Angular application to Play! Framework

Tags: javascript, java, json, angularjs, playframework

I am getting the following error from the browser debugger:

> Origin http://localhost:8000 not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

However I *have* set the header in my `Global.java` file in my API:

**Global.java**

```
@Override
public Promise<SimpleResult> call(Http.Context ctx) throws java.lang.Throwable {
    Promise<SimpleResult> result = this.delegate.call(ctx);
    Http.Response response = ctx.response();
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    return result;
}
```

Here is my the API route I am hitting.

**routes**

```
POST        /api/users/insertuser                      @controllers.UserController.insertUser
```

And here is the controller method:

**UserController.java**

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public Result insertUser() {
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
    String email = json.findPath("email").asText();
    String username = json.findPath("username").asText();
    String password = json.findPath("password").asText();
    if(email == null || username == null || password == null) {
      return badRequest("Missing parameter[s]");
    } else {
        User user = new User(username, email, false, password, getDate(), getDate());
        repo.insertUser(user);
        return getUserByEmail(email);
    }
}
```

Here is my API call from my Angular application:

**userapiservice.js**

```
var factory = {};
var baseUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/users/';

factory.insertUser = function (user) {
  return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    url: baseUrl + 'insertuser/',
    params: { username: user.username, email: user.email, password: user.password }
  });
};
```

Is there something I am missing/doing wrong? Tried on a couple of browsers, been stuck on it for about a week now, I've been teaching myself as I go along and I've found the Play! documentation to be... okay.

Comment: did you try goggle with that error? CORS settings are wrong on api

Comment: Yes I did, in fact I got those CORS settings from Google, what have I set wrong?

Comment: make sure OPTIONS requests are allowed. I don't know anything about `play` but the problem is definitely CORS  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first add preflight request

```
OPTIONS   /*all                                     controllers.Application.preflight(all)
```

---

```
public static Result preflight(String all) {
    response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response().setHeader("Allow", "*");
    response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH");
    response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Referer, User-Agent, access_token, mode");
    return ok();
}
```

but remember

```
@Override
    public Promise<SimpleResult> call(Http.Context ctx) throws java.lang.Throwable {
        Promise<SimpleResult> result = this.delegate.call(ctx);
        Http.Response response = ctx.response();
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        return result;
    }
```

call doesn't work on internal server error