# Angular2 + Play Framework - cannot post json with http.post() method

Tags: angular, http, playframework, request

I have a simple angular2 script using http.post():

```
createOrder(order: Order) {
    console.log('create');
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    const body = JSON.stringify(order);
    console.log(body);
    this.http.post(`http://localhost:9000/api/orders`, body, options)
      .map(res => res.json()).subscribe();
  }
```

and my server side code to handle a request:

```
def create() = Action(parse.json) { request =>
    def product: OrderResource = OrderService.addOrder(request)

    Created("Order for " + product.email + " created.")
      .withHeaders(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN -> "*", ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS -> "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
  }
```

When I do a post i get an 404 error:
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/api/orders. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404`

**General:**
Request URL:http://localhost:9000/api/orders
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:[::1]:9000
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

**Response Headers**
Content-Length:6953
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 19 Jun 2017 07:29:30 GMT

**Request Headers**
Accept:*/*
Access-Control-Request-Headers:access-control-allow-origin,content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:9000

I don't know why I cannot do a simple post? When I do same from postman as a client everything is ok, but from Angular it does not work.
Why this request is an `Options` method rather then `Post`?

Comment: This is a probem with cors (cross origin ressource sharing).

You need to allow you server to expose ressource from another domain (localhost:4200) for example

Comment: But I set cors on server and client

Comment: Normally the cors only need to be configure to the server side. The browser male the OPTION call to know if he can access to the ressource. So if the OPTION call isn't good (and don't return the Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers), you have an error.

It's working with postman because the cors security is only available on browsers

Comment: So how can I fix it?

Comment: depend on you'r back techno, if you use a framework or not

Comment: I use play framework

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844178/unable-to-post-data-from-angular-application-to-play-framework/31848735#31848735

Comment: I created CORS filters and now it works fine. Thx.